# Visual Studio Style Undo/Redo Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, ribbon, undo-redo

I want to make a Ribbon Undo/Redo Button that looks and functions like Visual Studio's Undo/Redo Buttons.
I've been trying to use RibbonSplitButton to mimic the behavior, but it turns out it only accepts menuitems inside its Items Property.
Does anybody have an idea on how to go about this?
Thanks in Advance.

p.s. worst case scenario would be writing a custom control to override the existing splitbutton but does anybody know what to override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be a problem that only MenuItems are allowed as long as you can bind to it using an ItemsSource property or the like. Your application just needs a Undo and Redo stack of commands which should be provide methods for Undo/Redo and a UI friendly display string. These stacks can then be bound to the list and hopefully DataTemplated to show the display string and call the right methods upon click.

Comment: yes but the menu would not be scrollable.. if the stacks get too long it will extend beyond the screen.. anyways.. I have adopted a History screen rather than undo/redo stacks on the ribbon itself.. thanks for answering..